# Firebase Crashlytics reports InflateException: ResourceNotFoundException for a Trend TaintArt for 4x6

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-inflate, inflate-exception, firebase-crash-reporting

My app is failing on a Trend TaintArt for x86 running Android 7.1.2 when it tries to inflate a layout containing an ImageView. The crash reports that the Drawable doesn't exist:

[image]

Yet, the Drawable (ic_list_white) is present:

[image]

Odd thing is, this seems the only device that's having the problem. Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: Do you use app bandle (*.aab) or (*.apk) ?

Comment: .aab. Why do you ask?

Comment: Any update on this? I also see this issue.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out this device, Trend TaintArt for x86, is bogus; there's no such device. Several other Crashlytics reports have since come in, also for bogus devices, including Batmobile Defy Mini and Huawei Enjoy 9S running Android 4.3.1 (the real Enjoy 9S [came out in 2019](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_enjoy_9s-9644.php) and is shipped with Android 9). I reported this to the Firebase support team and am awaiting their reply. I suspect someone is trying to reverse engineer my app.

Comment: Same problem here. Any news?

Comment: @pauminku See my comment above. You can try obfuscating your code, like I did, but then it's harder to debug errors.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this issue is happening only on google devices for automatic tests ([Play protect](https://www.android.com/play-protect/), [Pre-launch report](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/pre-launch-crash-reports), etc.).

I have come to this conclusion because, in our app, this error is happening only on few devices (2 or 3) and only on first hours after publishing an app to google play.

So I think we can safely ignore this issue in similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

We faced with the same problem after migrating to app bundle. I'm not sure but seems that device doesn't get all required splits. Seems it happens when you app is installed not from Google Play.

we use smt like this in Application#onCreate()

```
fun onCreate() {
    MissingSplitsManagerFactory.create(this).let { splitFactory -> 
                if(splitFactory.isMissingRequiredSplits) {
                    logEventToFirebaseMissingRequiredSplits()
                    splitFactory.disableAppIfMissingRequiredSplits()
                }
     }
}
```

take a look at [known_issues](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#known_issues) and [MissingSplitsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/missingsplits/MissingSplitsManager)

Answer (score 0):

I also see these kind of crashes from time to time in crashlytics.
the last time it was from a version that I haven't even released.
but I had uploaded the file to virustotal.com

therefore I think these messages are generated during a virusscan.
the virusscanner starts the app in a protected environment to see if it does something harmful. sometimes this leads to crashes.